# setstate is not rerendering child components when called from componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Parent component from which I am setting

```
interface SignUpPropModel {}
interface SignUpState{
    form:(InputProps&{desc: string})[];
}
export class SignUp extends Component<SignUpPropModel, SignUpState > {
    state: SignUpState = {
        form:[]
    }
    constructor(props:SignUpPropModel){
        super(props)
        this.state.form = [{
                type:"text",
                classnames:"form-control",
                id: "username",
                name: "username",
                isvalid: false,
                placeholder:"Username",
                value:'',
                desc:'Username'
            }]            
    }
    componentDidMount() {
            let form = [...this.state.form];
            if(form){
                form[0].isvalid=false;
                this.setState({form: form});
            }  
    }
    render(){
        return (
                    <form className='my-3'>
                        {this.state.form?.map((inputProps) => ( 
                                    <div key={inputProps.id} className="form-group mx-3" >
                                        <label htmlFor={inputProps.id}>{inputProps.desc}</label>
                                        <Input  {...inputProps}/>
                                    </div>)) }
                    </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Input Component -

```
interface IProps{
    type:'text'|'checkbox'|'radio'|'password';
    value?: any;
    name?: string;
    id?:string;
    onClick?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>) => void);
    onChange?:((event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void);
    classnames: string;
    placeholder?: any;
}
export interface InputProps extends IProps{
    isvalid?: boolean;
}
interface InputState{
    isvalid: boolean|undefined;
}
export class Input extends Component<InputProps, InputState>{
    iProps: IProps|null = null;
    state: InputState= {
        isvalid: true
    }
    constructor(props: InputProps){
        super(props);
        ({isvalid: this.state.isvalid, ...this.iProps} = this.props);
        this.state.isvalid = this.state.isvalid===undefined ? true: this.props.isvalid;          
    }
    render(){
        return (
                <input className={ this.state.isvalid===true ? this.iProps?.classnames : 'is-invalid' + ' ' + this.props.classnames} {...this.iProps}   />
        )
    }
}
```

Input is a child component. It renders the first time. In the `componentDidMount` os parent component, I am changing the state of the parent component using `setState`. I verified that the state of the parent component is changed but somehow `render` is not triggered by React. Thus, the change of state is not getting reflected in the child component.

Kindly help me to find what's wrong with my code.

Comment: but `componentDidMount` is only called once, so why would it rerender?

Comment: I am using `this.setState({form: form});` which should rerender the child components

Comment: so nothing is displayed in `<Input />`?

Comment: The previous state of <Input /> is displayed. New changes are not reflected in the child-component. The component is not rerendered.

Comment: can you create a sandbox to replicate this/

Comment: I don't think you are rendering anything new in the child

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tqsg5x?file=Hello.tsx

Comment: im getting a cross origin error in the browser do you know why?

Comment: ok it's working

Comment: what are you actually expecting to happen? there is nothing working to setState, your functions are just console.logging stuff

Comment: If I assign `form[0].isvalid=false` and pass in setState (which I am doing in componentDidMount) , then a red border should be  there on the first element in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer to this issue.

I was assuming that whenever React executes `render`, it recreates the component. i.e. I was assuming that rerendering will trigger the constructor of `Input` component. Finally, I did some debugging in the application and found that `constructor` won't be executed while re-rendering. Thus, I was not getting updated value in the `state` of `Input`.

Found out that I have to use a lifecycle method named `componentDidUpdate` in `Input`.

```
 componentDidUpdate(){
        const isvalid = this.props.isvalid===undefined ? true: this.props.isvalid;
        if(this.state.isvalid !== isvalid)
            this.setState({isvalid: isvalid});
    }
```

I added this in `Input` and the issue is resolved.